# What is the reason to put caller in interruptible/non interruptible state after call to mutex_lock and mutex_lock_interruptible API?

Tags: multithreading, linux-kernel, synchronization, mutex, critical-section

mutex API in linux provides different functions to lock mutex, like mutex_lock/mutex_lock_interruptible.. what will be the reason to put your thread in uninterruptible wait? i mean a thread is already waiting.. why cant we execute interrupts in the meantime? I can't think of the possible scenarios (probably because i am ignorant), please throw some light.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not about blocking interrupts. In fact it would make no sense, the entire point of blocking with a mutex is to get off the cpu.

uninterruptible sleep is about not being woken up before the condition you are waiting for (here: the lock) is met.